# Cant pass my test with my post http function with jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, httpbackend

I can't understand why my post function doesn't pass my jasmine test. I think that issues with $httpBackend is very poor in AngularJS documentation

This is my code:

```
.controller('SystemControllerNg',
    ['sweetAlertService', 'dataExchangeService', function(sweetAlertService, dataExchangeService) {

    var self = this;
    self.all_products = [];

    /*
        Get product from database
    */
    self.getProductsFromDatabase = function() {

        var success = function(response) {
            self.all_products = response.data;
        };

        var error = function(errResponse) {
            console.log('Error getting products from database');
        };

        dataExchangeService.getProducts().then(success, error);
    };
    /*
        End get product
    */

    /*
        Send product to database
    */
    self.sendProductToDatabase = function(type) {
        var success = function(response) {
            self.getProductsFromDatabase();
        };

        var error = function(errResponse) {
            console.log('Error sending product to database');
        };

        dataExchangeService.sendProduct({
            "owner": 1,
            "name": self.product_input,
            "type": true,
            "size": 0,
            //"assign_category": self.categoryName_id
            "assign_category": null
        }).then(success, error);
    };
    /*
        End send product
    */

    /*
        Functions RUNNING in the background
    */
        self.getProductsFromDatabase();
    /*
        End functions RUNNING in the background
    */
}])

.factory('dataExchangeService', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        getProducts: function() {
            return $http.get('/api/v1/Products/');
        },
        sendProduct: function(dataObject) {
            return $http.post('/api/v1/Products/', dataObject);
        }
    };
}]);
```

and tests code:

```
describe('Testing services in "Aplication" module', function () {
    beforeEach(module('Aplication'));

    describe('SystemControllerNg controller', function () {

        var ctrl, mockBackend;

        beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $httpBackend) {
            mockBackend = $httpBackend;

            ctrl = $controller('SystemControllerNg');
        }));

        //In this issue everything is ok
        it('it should load products from database', function() {
            expect(ctrl.all_products).toEqual([]);

            var resObj = {
                "owner": 1,
                "name": "",
                "type": true,
                "size": 0,
                "assign_category": null
            };

            mockBackend.expectGET('/api/v1/Products/')
                .respond([ resObj ]);

            mockBackend.flush();

            expect(ctrl.all_products).toEqual([ resObj ]);
        });

        it('it should send product to database', function() {
            //expect(ctrl.all_products).toEqual([]);

            var dataObject = {
                "owner": 1,
                "name": "product",
                "type": true,
                "size": 0,
                "assign_category": null
            };

            //I don't know why can't pass it :|
            mockBackend.expectPOST('/api/v1/Products/', dataObject).respond(201, {});

            mockBackend.flush();

            //expect(ctrl.all_products).toEqual([ dataObject ]);
        });

        afterEach(function() {
            mockBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
            mockBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
        });
    });
});
```

First test *expectGET* work great, but why *expectPOST* doesn't? If you know why it doesn't work I will be very grateful.

This is my log console:
[image: console log]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Two points here:

1) In your test you are not calling the controller method that would call the service that would make the POST event happen.

```
    it('it should send product to database', function() {
        //expect(ctrl.all_products).toEqual([]);

        var dataObject = {
            "owner": 1,
            "name": "product",
            "type": true,
            "size": 0,
            "assign_category": null
        };

        //I don't know why can't pass it :|
        mockBackend.expectPOST('/api/v1/Products/', dataObject).respond(201, {});
        //this is missing from your test
        ctrl.sendProductToDatabase();

        mockBackend.flush();
        scope.$digest();

        expect(ctrl.all_products).toEqual([ dataObject ]);
    });
```

2) When you test a controller that calls methods of a service, you should be mocking the service and injecting it into the controller during the test setup. Your tests for the controller should be testing what the controller does, not what the service does. Test your services independently.

Comment: 1) Thanks, but I tried also `ctrl.sendProductToDatabase();` before and it still didn't work. I know that it's the most logical solution.. 2) You're probably right and I will try it also, but it doesn't sense for me, because if it would be a solution then function: `mockBackend.expectGET('/api/v1/Products/').respond([ resObj ]);` should be also doesn't work yes?

Comment: Have you tried adding a digest cycle to the process? Something similar to what I've added to my answer. You'd have to define the scope variable in your test setup first.

Comment: It didn't help, but I guessed that I misunderstand how unit tests work in angulajs. Thank you very much for your help. I gonna to write it here my solution when I do it correctly